# Getting a '403 Forbidden' when calling the Pull Request API on VSTS

Tags: git, azure-devops-rest-api

For other APIs that I'm calling (including Analytics), it all seems to work fine, but when I try to make any Pull Request queries, I get a `403 Forbidden`.

The calls are being made by my private Windows agent with PAT authorised with all scopes. It is using `@{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}`.

Is there some other permission I need to set somewhere?

Edit 1:

If I use `$header =  @{Authorization = "Basic <hard coded base64 encoded string used in the header for my Postman queries>"}`, it works.

Comment: What's the request body of application/json did you use to create a PR?

Comment: `$body = @{"status" = "abandoned"} | ConvertTo-Json`

Comment: Also, please see Edit 1.

Comment: I added an example powershell script to create a PR, you can have a try.

Comment: Do you grant `Contribute to pull requests` permission to Project Collection  Build Service (XXX) user? (Version control admin page > Select a repository)?

Comment: Awesome! No it wasn't set to Allow but setting it now makes it work. On a side note, why are there so many different places under VSTS where you can adjust security settings? There's three I've counted so far: _admin/security, _admin/_versioncontrol, _details/security/tokens.

Comment: PS: Your comment should be an accepted answer.

Comment: Great! I post an answer that you can accept as answer. Regarding security of vsts, they are grouped by different features, which is benefit for us to manage.

Comment: I understand grouping of security based on features, but the way the UI/UX is organised on the webpage makes navigation/interaction quite tedious. Just my thoughts. Would help if it were all accessible under a top level 'Security' tab (or similar) with feature level groupings underneath. Anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to grant `Contribute to pull requests` permission to `Project Collection Build Service (XXX)` user. (Version control admin page > Select a repository)