# Why am I getting a 400 - Bad Request when completing a pull request using the VSTS API

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I'm guessing this is a permission issue. I know the URI and body, etc are all correct, as it works fine with a different authorisation in the header.

I tried adjusting permissions under _admin/_versioncontrol to 'Allow', as per what had worked for me when creating pull requests. Ref:
[Getting a '403 Forbidden' when calling the Pull Request API on VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49020015/getting-a-403-forbidden-when-calling-the-pull-request-api-on-vsts)

But while I can create/abandon requests just fine, I can't seem to auto-complete them.

What am I missing?

**Edit 1 (based on starian chen-MSFT's request):**

When I catch the exception in my powershell script and do a `Write-Output $_.Exception`, I get this:

```
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

When I remove the `Invoke-RestMethod` from a try-catch block, I get this printed to the consolve output:

```
2018-03-10T03:22:13.3706092Z Calling https://&lt;my_vsts_account&gt;.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/git/repositories/&lt;my_git_repo_id&gt;/pullRequests/&lt;my_pr_id&gt;?api-version=3.0 with body:
2018-03-10T03:22:13.3727606Z {
2018-03-10T03:22:13.3727838Z     &quot;autoCompleteSetBy&quot;:  {
2018-03-10T03:22:13.3728135Z                               &quot;id&quot;:  &quot;aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee&quot;
2018-03-10T03:22:13.3728388Z                           },
2018-03-10T03:22:13.3728593Z     &quot;completionOptions&quot;:  {
2018-03-10T03:22:13.3728942Z                               &quot;mergeCommitMessage&quot;:  &quot;Auto completing pull request&quot;,
2018-03-10T03:22:13.3729252Z                               &quot;squashMerge&quot;:  &quot;false&quot;,
2018-03-10T03:22:13.3729845Z                               &quot;deleteSourceBranch&quot;:  &quot;false&quot;
2018-03-10T03:22:13.3730053Z                           }
2018-03-10T03:22:13.3730229Z }
2018-03-10T03:22:13.6040452Z ##[error]Invoke-RestMethod : {&quot;$id&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;innerException&quot;:null,&quot;message&quot;:&quot;Invalid argument value.\r\nParameter name: Invalid 
pull request auto complete set by id. Valid values are either the current user identity id, or an empty guid (to unset 
auto complete).&quot;,&quot;typeName&quot;:&quot;Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebServer.InvalidArgumentValueException, 
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebServer&quot;,&quot;typeKey&quot;:&quot;InvalidArgumentValueException&quot;,&quot;errorCode&quot;:0,&quot;eventId&quot;:0}
At C:\Development\.agent\scripts\do-ci.ps1:562 char:33
+ ... ry_result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Patch -UseDefaultCred ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExc 
   eption
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Once again, when I copy paste the above URI and body into Postman, it works perfectly fine. Seeing that the only difference between my Powershell script and the Postman call is the authorization header, it means this is a permission issue, and a permission issue alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the same user id (current authorized user) to update pull request to Auto-Complete through REST API (`"autoCompleteSetBy":{"id":xxx}`), otherwise you will get 400 error.

You can update pull request status to Completed through REST API if you just want to complete the pull request.

Update:

Simple code to create pull request and get user's id:

```
param(
[string]$project,
[string]$repo,
[string]$sourceBranch,
[string]$targetBranch,
[string]$title,
[string]$des,
[string]$token
)
$bodyObj=@{
  "sourceRefName"="refs/heads/$sourceBranch";
  "targetRefName"= "refs/heads/$targetBranch";
  "title"= "$title";
  "description"="$des";
}
$bodyJson=$bodyObj| ConvertTo-Json
$uri="https://XXX.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repo/pullRequests?api-version=3.0"
Write-Output $bodyJson
Write-Output $uri
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "test",$token)))
$result=Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $Uri -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Body $bodyJson
$serviceId=$result.createdBy.id
Write-Host $serviceId
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=userId;]$serviceId"
```

Comment: To quote what I said in my question: "I know the URI and body, etc are all correct, as it works fine with a different authorisation in the header."

Comment: This is a permission issue, not a content one.

Comment: I'd be interested to know how to get more detail. I'm calling this from a powershell script. I'm placing `Invoke-RestMethod` in a `try` block and catching `$_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription` which only gives me "Bad Request".

Comment: Try to get `$_.Exception.Message` or `$_.Exception`

Comment: Output the whole error: `Write-Output $_` or remove try catch code to throw the error directly, you may send the pull request through PostMan tool to do test.

Comment: Please see Edit 1.

Comment: @Ash The user (autoCompleteSetBy id) must be the same as the current authorized user (The user specified in authorization header)

Comment: Ah. I decoded the authorization header used by Postman (working) and indeed it has the same user as the autoCompleteSetBy id. How do I get the user id associated with the private build agent I'm running the powershell script on? When I set up the agent, all I had to work with was the PAT; but this was not associated to an actual user.

Comment: @Ash It uses build service account (project collection build service (xxx)), do not find the simple way to get that user's id, you can create the pull request during build with that user (system.accesstoken), then get the user's id in response (createdBy>Id)

Comment: sorry I don't quite follow how I can get the user id for the build service account. Could you please edit your answer (if possible) with some sample powershell code to retrieve the user id via API?

Comment: Thanks. Before I accept the answer, just couple quick questions, 1) Is there a way to get build user's id through VSTS (not API)? 2) Can the id change? Because if not, I could save the user id when an actual pull request gets created and use it for future autocompletes.

Comment: @Ash There isn't the way to get build service user's id directly, but you can check the request (F12 developer tool) related to build service user, for example: 1. go to version control admin page 2. Select build service user 3. change permission 4. Open developer too (press F12) 5. Click Save changes 6. Check the current request's body (TeamFoundationId value is the user's id). I don't think the user's id will be changed.